# What ELF `e_flags` are defined for TI MSP430(X)

Tags: elf

I have an MSP430 ELF executable file whose `e_flags` field is `0x0000000E`. I cannot find any documentation for `e_flags` for this architecture. The application note "MSP430 Embedded Application Binary Interface" from TI explicitly states:

> There are no MSP430-specific flags for `e_flags` field.

I was hoping that these flags could help me identify whether the binary is contains instructions in the base MSP430 or the extended MSP430X ISA. Are they documented anywhere?

Comment: Do you know what compiler produced your file?

Comment: I don't see a lot of hints as to which compiler built it. I see the string "MSP430F148 FreeRTOS Demo program" and not much else. The symbols are consistent with FreeRTOS.

Answer (score 0):

I could find [this patch set](https://gist.github.com/hotovson/1323822) with the comment:

```
/* Pre-uniarch versions of binutils stored machine types in the
 * e_flags field, with values up to 471 decimal.  Now we store the
 * machine type in the e_mach field, and use e_flags to identify the
 * characteristics of the code.
 *
 * Use the following flag to indicate that this object file uses the
 * uniarch flag layout. */
#define EF_MSP430_UNIARCH        0x10000000

#define EF_MSP430_ARCH_430       0x00000000
#define EF_MSP430_ARCH_430X      0x00000001
#define EF_MSP430_ARCH           0x000000FF
#if 0
/* These are symbol-associated, not archive-associated, attributes.
 * Not sure what to do with them. */
#define EF_MSP430_CPU_430        0x00000000
#define EF_MSP430_CPU_430X       0x00000200
#define EF_MSP430_CPU_430XV2     0x00000300
#define EF_MSP430_CPU            0x00000300
#define EF_MSP430_MPY_NONE       0x00000000
#define EF_MSP430_MPY_16         0x00001000
#define EF_MSP430_MPY_16_SE      (0x00008000 + EF_MSP430_MPY_16)
#define EF_MSP430_MPY_32         0x00002000
#define EF_MSP430_MPY_32_DW      (0x00008000 + EF_MSP430_MPY_32)
#define EF_MSP430_MPY_CLASS      0x00003000
#define EF_MSP430_MPY            0x0000F000
#define EF_MSP430_CODE_NEAR      0x00010000
#define EF_MSP430_CODE_FAR       0x00020000
#define EF_MSP430_CODE_MIXED     0x00030000
#define EF_MSP430_CODE           0x00030000
#define EF_MSP430_DATA_NEAR      0x00040000
#define EF_MSP430_DATA_FAR       0x00080000
#define EF_MSP430_DATA_MIXED     0x000c0000
#define EF_MSP430_DATA           0x000c0000
#define EF_MSP430_A20            0x000F0000
#endif
```

And apparrently [an older version](http://web.mit.edu/freebsd/head/contrib/binutils/include/elf/msp430.h):

```
/* Processor specific flags for the ELF header e_flags field.  */
#define EF_MSP430_MACH      0xff

#define E_MSP430_MACH_MSP430x11  11
#define E_MSP430_MACH_MSP430x11x1  110
#define E_MSP430_MACH_MSP430x12  12
#define E_MSP430_MACH_MSP430x13  13
#define E_MSP430_MACH_MSP430x14  14
#define E_MSP430_MACH_MSP430x15  15
#define E_MSP430_MACH_MSP430x16  16
#define E_MSP430_MACH_MSP430x31  31
#define E_MSP430_MACH_MSP430x32  32
#define E_MSP430_MACH_MSP430x33  33
#define E_MSP430_MACH_MSP430x41  41
#define E_MSP430_MACH_MSP430x42  42
#define E_MSP430_MACH_MSP430x43  43
#define E_MSP430_MACH_MSP430x44  44
```